# How to push both the client side and server side project folders together as a one project (api + front end) on github?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, github, react-fullstack

I have completed my project.

**My stack :**

```
Front-End UI => Reactjs
Back-End => Nodejs/Expressjs + MongoDB
```

And below is my `project structure` containing both the folders:

```
project_Name > client + server
```

`project_Name` is the main folder
`client` and `server` are the separate folders both are inside `project_Name` folder.
And inside `client` and `server` folder I have installed the respective `npm modules (reactjs + nodejs)`

My `API end point` is running on `localhost:8000`
and `reactjs` on `localhost:5000`

So now I want to add my project to `github` repository.
I am confused how to achieve that?
Do I need to push both client and server side code on separate 2 different gits?

Or

I need to upload just `project_Name` folder containing both side project files?
But is it so then how can I do that?
Since before pushing to `git`, the directory should have the `package.json` file and `node_modules` which will be only inside the `client` and `server` side folders.

These are the `git` commands to push the project I am using:

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/vik.........git
git push -u origin main
```

But I don't know in which folder I have to initiate the `repository` first?
Let me know the solution please .
Thanks!

Comment: You completed the project *before* getting it under version control? That was a really bad idea. But git doesn't care much about what exact files and folders you're tracking (and you'd usually ignore node_modules from the repo), so it's up to you whether you want to maintain one or two repos for this.

Comment: Tell me how to achieve that with one single folder?

Comment: ...run those commands in your question in that one single folder?

Answer (score 8):

If your project that you created has it's own folder then what you would need to do is:

Root Folder: Project
./client
./server

1. Initiate .git from your ROOT FOLDER.
2. git add . (which then adds all the files)
3. git commit... And so on. Feel free to comment if you need any help!

It'll add all your files in one go, so don't worry so much and it won't push any empty folders.

There's some instances where create-react-app, will create a git repo on it's own.
On your file explorer look for the hidden files, and be sure to delete that .git folder in your client before pushing your stuff, it'll throw you an error.

run NPM install on your main folder, it'll create a package.json for you.
Try not to think about it so hard and take it slow.

Hopes this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use this structure:

```
  -projectName: folder
     - frontend: folder
        - package.json
     - backend: folder
        - package.json
     - package.json
```

For executing the app you can use github actions:

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions

https://github.com/features/actions

OR

You can also use services like heroku or firebase, see my project (it is just a simple project for resolving this problem you are asking for)

https://github.com/simCecca/InformationVisualizationWorldWide

The structure is:

```
 -projectName: folder 
     - frontend: folder 
        - package.json
     backend code
     package.json // containing the BE dependencies and the dependencies for the 
                     deploy in heroku in this case
```

https://dashboard.heroku.com/

I hope I responded to your question, if I'have not, please reply to this response

Comment: I want this structure the first one: -projectName: folder
     - frontend: folder
        - package.json
     - backend: folder
        - package.json
     - package.json

Comment: But How to develop one more package.json file for main Project folder now? I have the respective project folder's package.json inside client and server folder.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i found the answer after 2 hours

to push your folder in format like this:

```
 -projectName: folder
     - frontend: folder
        - package.json
     - backend: folder
        - package.json
     - package.json
```

you have to follow the following steps:

1. Open the gitbash terminal
2. first `git init` ouside the client and server folder
3. then delete the `.git` folder from client folder if you using any **frontend
   framework** like (**reactJs**, **nextJs**)
4. Then outside the client and server folder **instead of** using `git add .`,   use **`git add ./client`** it removes the all node modules and only puts the json file to  the github.
5. Do the same for server folder
6. remember both folders have their .gitignore file separately but you push only the outside of the both folders git to github.
7. now do regular github things like `git commit -m"initial commit"`,`git remote add origin lkdjfhgoiuehg.git` , `git push origin master`

Then you are good to go!

Answer (score 1):

just copy and paste the .gitignore file in both frontend and backend folder, git will not upload node_modules folder in git repository.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the .gitignore file in the root folder (in same level as client and server) and inside that this line: node_modules/

this will ignore node_modules of both client and server.

after that initialize git:

1. Git init
2. git add .
3. git commit -m 'commit message'
4. git push -u origin master

Now you can visit GitHub repositories and confirm there isn't node_modules folder anymore

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node_modules and push it from the root.

Answer (score 0):

After creating two folders named **client** and **backend** in a root folder(suppose the name is: **my-project**). Now we would like to push our code to remote like this.

a) create a repo named **my-project** in **GitHub**(same name as the root folder)
b)checking in the terminal of my local to check if it is in the root or not.
c)from root:  **my-project** % run all the following commands.

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/vik.........git
git push -u origin main
```

d) now from the root in each folder[**client** and **backend**] create a **.gitignore** file and write node_modules to ignore node_modules if needed.

```
e)git add .
f)git commit -m 'all codes is pushed to remote'
g)git push origin main
```

Now all codes are in the remote.
If any code is changed for example in the **client**.

```
a) cd client
b) git status
c9 git add ./ file name
d) git commit -m 'client code is pushed'
e) git push origin main
```

client code is now updated in remote too.
Hope it would help.